# How to make partition of list in coq

Tags: coq

I have a list of natural numbers and want to divide it into three lists with a ratio 3:2:1. Want to use partition function.Please guide me

Fixpoint partition (l:list A) : list A * list A :=
      match l with
        | nil => (nil, nil)
        | x :: tl => let (g,d) := partition tl in
          if f x then (x::g,d) else (g,x::d)
      end.

Comment: The `partition` function you define above does not let you split the list based on the length, instead it filters the list based on a predicate `f`.   Instead you should use a function `splitAt n` that splits a list x into a pair of lists (a,b) where a is the first n elements of x, and x = a ++ b.  Then simply `splitAt (length x/2) x` to get the first list you are looking for, and so on...

Comment: I have split function but it return list after finding n element.Compute split_at 5 [1;2;3;7;6;5]. = [1;2;3;7;6]
But I require pair (1, 6), similarly (3,6) from 3rd location 6th location in list having length l.
Can you share your code?

Comment: Just change your split_at to return a pair of both the first and second part of the list instead of just the first part.  It is a very standard program, and a good programming exercise to write if you are learning functional programming.  Which programming language do you usually use?

Comment: I highly recommend that you try to solve it yourself, but it can be disheartening to get stuck, so here is one way to do it - just look if you get stuck! `Fixpoint splitAt n {T} (a:list T) := match n, a with | S n', cons x a' => let (b, t) := splitAt n' a' in (cons x b, t) | 0,    a => (nil, a)  | S n', nil => (nil, nil) end.`

Comment: Thank you.But I am using this code.Fixpoint first n l :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | m :: l' => if beq_nat n m then []
               else m :: first n l'
  end.
Fixpoint second n l :=
  match l with
  | [] => l
  | m :: l' => if beq_nat n m then l'
               else second n l'
  end.
Fixpoint split_at n l :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | m :: l' => first n (m :: l') :: split_at n (second n (m :: l'))
  end.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is underspecified, but here are a couple pointers:

---

First, your function will likely be different from `partition`, because `partition` assumes the existence of a function which, given one element from the list, knows which part of the partition it belongs in.

However, given your loose specification, it seems that elements should belong in one of the three partitions not based on their own value, but rather on some property of the list in which they appear and how many other elements there are.

---

Here's one way you could approach this problem: in the absence of external constraint on the distribution of values in the partitions, you can obtain your 3:2:1 ratio by partitioning the list in 6 equal partitions, and then combining 3 partitions together, and separately 2 partitions together.

Now the problem will be to have a function to create `n` partitions. Depending on your skill level, and whether you will need to write proofs about the function, there could be different ways to go about it.

Writing an actual function that returns `n` list(s) for any `n` will require a dependent type with some `n`-ary product type. You could fake it by having a function:

```
get_partitions : list T -> (n : nat) -> (i : nat) -> list T
```

such that `get_partitions l n i` filters the elements of `l` at indices `i`, `i + n`, `i + 2n`, etc. (i.e. elements whose index is equal to `i` mod `n`).

Then you could obtain your six partitions as `get_partitions l 6 0`, `get_partitions l 6 1`, ..., `get_partitions l 6 5`.

This would be an easy-to-write solution, but might not be best for proving purposes... Someone might have better ideas. :-)